# Replacing Fragment does not work properly while swipeRefresh is running

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have fragment A which includes a SwipeRefresh and a RecycleView.
When user click on an Item in RecycleView, I replace a new Fragment which is B:

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                Item tem = mItems.get(position);
                // selected item
                Log.i(TAG, item.getTitle() + " clicked. Replacing fragment.");

                // We start the fragment transaction here. It is just an ordinary fragment transaction.
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_fragment,
                                FragmentB.newInstance(item,
                                        (int) view.getX(), (int) view.getY(),
                                        view.getWidth(), view.getHeight())
                        )
                                // We push the fragment transaction to back stack. User can go back to the
                                // previous fragment by pressing back button.
                        .addToBackStack("detail")
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

There is a problem :

When I start to refresh using SwipeRefresh, and it is still running, I click on an item (as you can see the code above), Fragment B will be replaced `under` Fragment A in the screen.
I can see Fragment B under my RecycleView in Fragment A! 
I am no longer able to scroll in recycleView since `onStop()` is called in Fragment A and `onCreateView` is called in Fragment B.

What could be the reason? do you have any workaround?

Addenda : Crash can be reproduce in google sample as well:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FragmentTransition/

Comment: Try this please:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29251199/4693713

hope it will helps you.

Comment: What is the difference of this with my code? :)

Comment: Dont use addToBackStack may be it will works..

Comment: That is what I wanted to have. Do you know what is that? why you suggest this?

Comment: This will put your previous fragment in the back stack..

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug. Google may fix it soon.

[Issue 78062](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78062)

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same question and I even didn't use addToBackStack,at first I think the fragment hasn't been replaced,but I start a new thread and try to find the old fragment by fragmentmanager and **find that it has been replaced**,I think what you see is not the real fragment,you can regard it as the phantom which the swipe view creates to show an animation.

**By coincidence,I find that if you setTransition() for the transaction and it will work properly,maybe the transition animation does the trick.**

Comment: Sorry,but I think it is not completely true,I have found another problem,see the comment of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27073879/4158334)