# SwipeRefreshLayout refresh conflict with fragmentTransactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

TLDR: here's my bug report : http://goo.gl/UgBFW2

Using a `SwipeRefreshLayout` if I press back and trigger either a `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackstack()`, `super.onBackPressed()` or `fragmentTransaction.replace()` right when the adapter triggers the views refresh, the two fragments overlap (a video showing the problem can be found in the top link).

I tried several things and adding a background is not a solution since the list fragment is in the foreground and the one clickable is the previous fragment.

Has anyone found a solution to this ?

[Replacing Fragment does not work properly while swipeRefresh is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253846/replacing-fragment-does-not-work-properly-while-swiperefresh-is-running)

Comment: I just ran into the same issue... Do you know if the have been any progress on your bug report? Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the fragment that contains the swipe

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (swipeRefreshLayout!=null) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        swipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
        swipeRefreshLayout.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do it in `onPause` instead of `onStop` method?

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug. Google may fix it in future.

[Android Issue 78062](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78062)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the SwipeToRefreshLayout inside a FrameLayout. It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue I Have Faced**

I was facing the same issue in appcompat-v7:25.1.0. 
I have tried all this below codes still the problem persist

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (swipeRefreshLayout!=null) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        swipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
        swipeRefreshLayout.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

**Solution**

If any one facing the same issue  Please downgrade appcompat to 25.0.1 and use the above snippet to stop animating the same. It is working fine for me